# Emacs use .emacs by default instead .emacs.d/init.el

Tags: emacs

When I configure variable through M-x customize-variable, emacs save it to .emacs instead .emacs.d/init.el. On Windows I have no this problem, it uses init.el by default. But on Linux it creates me .emacs file. How to make emacs force use .emacs.d/init.el ?

Comment: I was sure this question would be a duplicate, but I failed to find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Stop Emacs
- *Rename* your `~/.emacs` file to `~/.emacs.d/init.el`
- Run Emacs

See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Find-Init.html for details.